# Gulp browserify with directory as source

Tags: gulp, browserify

I'm trying to set up a gulp task in which browserify works its way through a directory instead of one specific file.

Currently my task is looking like this

```
gulp.task('javascript', function () {
  var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
    var b = browserify(filename);
    return b.bundle();  
  });

  return gulp.src(['js/src/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(browserified)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js/*.js'));
});
```

Which is basically a tweaked version of the code explained in this article: https://wehavefaces.net/gulp-browserify-the-gulp-y-way-bb359b3f9623

However, I'm getting a `TypeError: dest.write is not a function` error. I'm getting the `dest.write` error because something changed in the `browserify` or `vinyl-transform` API, according to this Github issue: https://github.com/hughsk/vinyl-transform/issues/7

What would be a (preferably as elegant as this) way to make browserify work through a directory and return all files in there in the `dist` folder.

Comment: There's an example in the official docs that might help you: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-with-globs.md
Basically you want to replace `gulp.src` with `globby`.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti Thanks, but this still only compiles one script. Can't define multiple sources...

Comment: @BobWassermann did you end up getting this solved?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by getting rid of vinyl-transform in favor of vinyl-source-stream and vinyl-buffer directly. I found this example gist, which solved my build problems for me:
https://gist.github.com/stoikerty/cfa49330a9609f6f8d2d